# LINQ returning strange value using Select on a string

Tags: c#, linq

This code return the int 49

```
IEnumerable<int> numbersList = numbers.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

int sum = numbersList.Sum();
```

the numbers variable is a string with the value 1.

if I use

```
numbers.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

Then I get the correct answer. I know split passes back a string array so I used a string array with a single value of 1 instead of splitting and that worked too.

```
string[] sa = new string[] { "1" }
```

My question is does anyone know why using the select on a string return the wrong value?

Thanks.

Comment: if items are comma seperated then obviously first statement will give wrong result

Comment: what does your string look like in `numbers`

Comment: It converts char `1` into integer, which is 49 in ASCII table.

Comment: For some reason you are getting the character code of `'1'`, but that's not anywhere in the code that you are showing. Exactly what code are you running to get that?

Comment: @Guffa `the numbers variable is a string with the value 1`

Comment: @Rawling: Ah, now I see it, the first code is different from the second...

Comment: "1".Select(x => x).ToArray() == new char[]{ '1' }, with `Convert.ToInt32` becomes `Convert.ToInt32('1')` == `Convert.ToInt32(49)` == `49`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `numbers.Select()` you treat the string as a collection. It is a collection, but not a collection of substrings but a collection of characters.

You get the same result as if `numbers` was an array of characters, i.e `{ '1' }`.

The result of `Convert.ToInt32('1')` is the character code for `'1'`, which is 49.

Answer (score 2):

The code is returning the ASCII code of the number 1:

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained *why*.

Answer (score 2):

The first method converts the char '1' to an int, the second converts the string "1" to an int. The first will return 49 (the ascii value of that character), the second will return 1.

You can convert a char representing an int to an int with:

```
c - '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the x inside the lambda expression is a Unicode character. 
Convert.ToInt32 converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the equivalent 32-bit signed integer. In your case this is 49.

In second case the x is a string. Convert.ToInt32 works differently with strings converting the number contained in this string to actual int representation, in this case 1.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ww9t2871%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)